# Understanding the efficiency of modified a IDDFS algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

I have an assignment question on IDDFS. The question is:

Suppose we do IDDFS. But in place of decreasing depths as 1,2,3,4..., we increase it as 1,2,4,8,16... i.e., double the depth in place of increasing it by 1. Which of the following is true for the modified IDDFS?

1. Optimal but not complete
2. Complete but not optimal
3. More efficient than standard IDDFS in the worst case
4. Less efficient than standard IDDFS in the worst case

**The answers given to this are options 2 and 4**. I can understand how option 2 is an answer but I do not understand how option 4 is the answer.

According to my understanding, in the worst case the whole tree will have to be expanded. But since standard IDDFS has lesser depths than the modified one, it has to go through more iterations to get to the goal than modified IDDFS whose depth limits are double that of the standard one. So shouldn't the answer be 3? Am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your solution lies at depth 3, in the worst case modified IDDFS will expand all nodes until depth 4 (except 1), while standard IDDFS will only expand all nodes until depth 3. Modified IDDFS is then less efficient.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).